problem when pulling ollama's llm using the cli
I've recently downloaded ollama from their official website then when i tried to pull one of the models using the command ollama pull mistral I've got this error:
`  ollama : The term 'ollama' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

ollama serve

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ollama:Stri  
ng) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException     `






i tried to install ollama as well from the cli, but nothing worked , so if you have any suggestions please tell me

Check if the Ollama path is configured in the system variables. If it is not, manually add the Ollama file path to the system variables.

yep that was the problem, thank you !
